# Repeated attribute in rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite

So I accidentaly made a model in Ruby on Rails on which I wrote an attribute twice, with the same name and type. If I check my migration it looks like this:

```
class CreateTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :table do |t|
      t.text :Total
      t.text :Total

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

The name is not really Table, but you get the idea.
My question is how will this be reflected on the db, since running the migrations caused no problem. I don't think it's posible to have to columns with the same id, so I'm guessing it was only created once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will create the column just once. Your table is valid. But i advise you to rollback the migration, delete the migration file and create a new migration with valid column names(Given no one else has pulled this change of yours).